# How to find volume and surface area of a spindle torus?

Tags: calculus, area, volume, solid-of-revolution

I know that you can use the formulas described in Pappus' centroid theorem, detailed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem). But does Pappus' centroid theorem hold true for all forms of a torus: ring, horn, and spindle? I found another website that uses Pappus' centroid theorem for the volume and surface area of a ring or horn torus, but a different formula for the spindle torus.

This is the formula listed for  the spindle torus:
$$
V = \frac23 \pi ( 2r^2 + R^2 ) \sqrt{r^2 - R^2} + \pi r^2 R \left[\pi + 2\arctan\left( \frac{R}{\sqrt{r^2 - R^2}} \right) \right]
$$
where $r$ is the minor radius and $R$ is the major radius.

Is this formula for the spindle torus' volume accurate, or do I just have to use Pappus' centroid theorem?

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4688580

Answer (score 0):

Pappus's Centroid Theorem assumes that the solid generated does not intersect itself so I would use the formula you listed since a spindle torus does intersect itself.